# How to work with HTTP Post in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to post some data on server but it goes to blank parameter at server side.I'm using HttpURLConnection for sending the data on server and getting response is correctly(Status="true") but at server side sending parameter is goes to blank.So I'm not able to show my uploaded data on website from android.Can someone help me to solve this issue why data goes to blank ?

Here is my code for post the data. This all code is in AsyncTask

```
JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
                try
                {
                    jsonObjSend.put("ActionDate", "2016-01-29 18:40:06");
                    jsonObjSend.put("ActivityId", strNewActivityId);
                    jsonObjSend.put("UserId", "163");
                    jsonObjSend.put("ObjectId", "96");
                    jsonObjSend.put("Name", "vaishali1_vaishali");
                    jsonObjSend.put("Remark", "testing android 2");
                    jsonObjSend.put("Status", "PENDING");
                    jsonObjSend.put("Type", "3");
                    jsonObjSend.put("starflag", "0");
                    jsonObjSend.put("HashTag", strHashTag);
                    jsonObjSend.put("Authentication_Token", str_Authentication_Token);

                }catch (JSONException je)
                {
                    je.printStackTrace();
                }

                String str = jsonObjSend.toString();
                Log.e(" str "," = "+str);

                String dataUrl = "http://103.24.4.60/xxxxx/MobileService.svc/Upd_Post_Activity";
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection urlConn;
                DataOutputStream printout;


                try {
                    url = new URL(dataUrl);
                    urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    urlConn.setDoInput(true);
                    urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
                    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    urlConn.connect();

                    printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
                    printout.writeBytes(jsonObjSend.toString());
                    printout.flush();
                    printout.close();

                    InputStream is = urlConn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    String line;
                    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                        response.append('\r');
                    }
                    rd.close();
                    responseStr = response.toString();
                    Log.d("Server response", responseStr);
                }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: tip: use Retrofit or Volley or etc Android Networking plugins. Do not write networking layer yourself.

Comment: Refer this links: http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android & http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89

Comment: Show your server code as the server is wrong sending such status.

Comment: `sending parameter is goes to blank.`. Which one?

Comment: All parameter is goes to empty and i received the responce from server status is true , but i put all the values in json  .

Comment: You were asked to post the server code. If you dont want that or are not able then at least comment. You should also tell what kind of server you use.

Comment: I don't understand what kind of server .

Comment: How are you receiving data at server side? Is it a webservice, if yes post web.xml code along with server code.

Comment: I can't post that code , because server side code is handle another person .I'll try .

Comment: Try to use Volley(https://github.com/adamrocker/volley) or retrofit(https://github.com/square/retrofit).

Comment: @p.ld does that mean you don't even know how he is parsing your json string ?

Comment: Yeah , that's the problem , and he is telling when i send the request he received all the parameter is blank at his side.

Comment: You are sending a json text. Is that the intention? Ask the server man. It could be that you have to send normal post parameters instead of a json text as you do now.